# OpenVPN multi-server set-up with single point of access

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, private-network

I've been looking on the internet for quite some time now, but I can't find a good tutorial/explanation for my case.

What I want to achieve is a `single point of access` that enables me to `connect to all servers in the pool`. Let's say I have 5 servers, which I all want to connect through SSH separately/individually. However, I don't want to have 5 different OpenVPN configurations (one for each server).

Simplified, I'm looking for a set-up that enables me to use one OpenVPN config, which connects to any of the servers (I don't mind which one). That connection puts me within the network of all servers, which enables me to connect to the other 4 servers as well by SSH directly on the OpenVPN server IP?

All servers are connected on a private network. So each VPS can access the other by a private IP like 192.168.1.X, etc. However, this would require me to connect to any server through OpenVPN and SSH from that server to the actual target server, making the OpenVPN server a `passthrough`, which I want to prevent.

I'm curious whether this is possible and how others handle such set-up requests as the internet is not addressing this set-up. At least I haven't been able to find one

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look to haproxy which could achieve what you are looking for.

Haproxy can proxyfy any traffic based on port, TCP or UDP. As long as openVPN can use a sigle port to connect (1194/UDP for example) this could do the trick.

Comment: That would allow the load balancing of the OpenVPN 'front-end' servers. But would this also allow me to connect with OpenVPN over the HA-Proxy to get to other servers on the private network?

Comment: As long as the VPN tunnel is on, you can go anywhere behind